# How to customize the collapsing point of navbar in bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

How do i customize the collapsing point of the navbar in bootstrap using this gem https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails-bootstrap

https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/tenant-dev/Capture.PNG?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAIPMD4H42JKYZFXEA&Expires=1390640628&Signature=rd4dCKYk%2BMlut8AAwJ6nXG5oF4Y%3D&x-amz-security-token=AQoDYXdzEFoawAKE6ucn61yjRPyPjNUoowSVPHHZyOp5LgCc10IL3hjCiNGnFYeug6%2B%2B0BLq8nS6mQN6aHQm%2B7t554Xp%2B2PYSiCisxayFlVXCiXiRX5F2v4X2kPQ/paKy5W24h9QrNDDAij0zaMO/ym6UkBrwE23TUJbd3VXdnDB3izZSk6oShV7edLK5RUMu6TsQDQsurp9Mxd9jkVT5AKWo7yMjLebCe6vkA9RgEsM99hdbq73xv4A4VhWNieBgKMxest8%2BpLtC0XiL%2BRywVO9Qnwiwuc%2BmvTcKvDHmXzAgbo9NcSZK4rZl87yUFO8qDVCUgmeQeeCL2DVR54Aiou/BoCfAIW1ukmRUe4sNgiqjRAFv1ESaHyMJIaecsMIk9oB5R8HiUMMRzga6XqJ569cjkP0EqoLfzP0z1ldXj8mlttK7wWwTIVO9iD3942XBQ%3D%3D

Comment: What is the "collapsing point of the navbar"? Screenshot please.

Comment: By default is set to 775px but i want to set it to 995px.

Comment: Please give a screenshot.

Comment: Screenshot is in the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with collapsing point and where are you stuck? I assume you mean something like hiding the navbar.

Normally Bootstrap doesn't provide a navbar "collapsing". But if it does have a look at the official documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/